# Calculate percentage from two groups

Tags: percentage

Imagine I have two groups of players:

- Group A plays tetris. It has 1000 registered players, and 6% (60) are active players;
- Group B plays pacman. It has 3000 registered players, and 4% (120) are active players;

In terms of percentage, Group A has more active players. But in terms absolute, Group B has more.

If I show the percentages in a graph for example, it will be misleading since it will show the highest group as the lowest. If I use the number of active players it will also be misleading because that doesn't take into account that one group has 3 times more registered players than the other, which means one group has more potential to have active players than the other.

How can I calculate a relative percentage, if such thing exists?

Comment: Why don't you just say, for every 1000 player 6 % in group A is active, and for every 1000 player 4 % is active players in group B?

Comment: @Thomas Can I simply do that? Is it correct to state like that? If yes, then fine.

Comment: Well, mathematically you can. You say the following "into account that one group has 3 times more registered players", then just downscale it to be comparable. Research, survey etc. do that. For every 1000 player, you find x % actively playing tetris. So yeah sure. But, of course you can point out the obvious later on. That you for example have a group consisting of 3 times as much people but relatively less active players. Then maybe you have an idea as a researcher of why group A, relatively, has more active players and vice versa - then you can report that.

Comment: @Thomas Ok, got it. Thanks. If you make an official answer, I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: It is all good @rlcabral, thank you. It was the least I could do. Hope it helped you on your way to finishing it all up.